# How to submit a form through a button outside the form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I want to submit a form through a button which is outside the form and do the validation to that form. I'm using the Form tag from react-bootstrap.

My code doesn't validate the form

```
<Form
    noValidate
    validated={validated}
    onSubmit={e=> this.handleSubmit(e)}>

    <Form.Control
        required
        placeholder="Product Name"
        onChange={e => this.setState({name: e.target.value })}
        pattern={"[A-Z a-z]{3,30}"}
    />
</Form>
<button type="button" value="send" onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)} className={"btn btn-primary"}>Save</button>
```

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    else
        this.AddProduct();

    this.setState({ validated: true });
}
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Consider refactoring. I can't think of a reason for your button to not be inside your form tag. Even if position of the elements are an issue...that's what css is for.

Comment: @ElroyJetson actually i want to make a form then a form then a button save for the whole page , this button must validate the first form only!

Answer (score 4):

Ideally: Don't do that. Form elements are a useful structural element.

Failing that. Add a `form` attribute to the button with the value equal to the `id` attribute of the form.

> **form** HTML5
>
> The form element that the button is associated with (its form owner). The value of the attribute must be the id attribute of a
>   `<form>` element in the same document. If this attribute is not
>   specified, the `<button>` element will be associated to an ancestor
>   `<form>` element, if one exists. This attribute enables you to
>   associate `<button>` elements to `<form>` elements anywhere within a
>   document, not just as descendants of `<form>` elements.

— [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)