# Submit several different React forms, with one button outside the components that manage those forms

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently working on a reactjs project, and I've been stuck on a concept for some time.
I have several forms, each managed by a component (Class) and I would like to submit these forms (all together) when I click on a button that is in another component. I use the **Reactstrap** library for the forms.

I went through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855233/is-it-possible-to-handle-several-forms-by-one-submit-button), and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025301/how-to-submit-a-form-through-a-button-outside-the-form) which are similar to mine but none of them fully helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to look for several solutions (using parent references) but none satisfied me. To solve my problem, I had to resort to **redux**. Create a state at the level of redux and connect the parent and the childrens to the store.
So as soon as the parent validates the submission (using a button) in the onClick function , the state (props if we use **mapStateToProps**) is modified and the components children and parent are re-rendered; and we can use the **componentWillReceiveProps** function to detect the changing of the props and submit the form.